How to specify font slant "slnt" when using NextJS?
I want to use a specific font slant for Inter, specifically slnt -8.
When loading with url through SCSS I can specify slnt -8 like so:
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:slnt,wght@-8,100..900&display=swap");

With next/font/google provided by NextJS I can specify the weight and styles of the font but not the slant
I would like to use next/font since it self hosts the font provided by Google. And yeah, just italic is "leaning" way too much.
I tried specifying slant during import like so:
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], style: ["normal", { slant: -8 }]}); 
or
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], style: ["normal", "slnt:-8"]}); 
or
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], style: ["normal"]}, slant: "-8"); 
All of the above either throw TS error or fail to load

slnt is a variable font design axis. In your case: Inter doesn't provide this axis (e.g unlike Roboto Flex) So you would need to load the italic variations also or choose a font including the slnt axis.

To achieve the specific slant (-8) for the Inter font when using next/font, you typically need to configure it through CSS or JavaScript directly. next/font simplifies the process of loading fonts, but it doesn't directly support all features available via Google Fonts' API parameters, such as slant adjustments.
Here’s how you can approach this:
CSS Import Method:
Since you want to use next/font for hosting the font and you need a specific slant (-8), you can still achieve this by directly importing and applying styles in your CSS. Here’s how you can do it:
/* styles/globals.css */
/* Import Inter font with specific slant */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;  /* Adjust weight as needed */
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Inter Regular'), local('Inter-Regular'),
       url('/fonts/inter-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-named-instance: 'Regular';  /* Optional: specify named instance */
  font-variation-settings: 'slnt' -8;  /* Specify the slant here */
}

In this example:
Replace /fonts/inter-regular.woff2 with the correct path to your hosted Inter font file provided by next/font.
Adjust font-weight, font-style, and font-variation-settings according to the font weights and slant you need.

How do I find the correct path to my hosted Inter font provided by next/font?
I can find the actual fonts in the .next/static/media folders after the build has been done, but including those fonts in the css seems wrong since it wont download the actual "slnt -8"? or am I wrong here
